# Has_one, Belongs_to migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, migration, models

I'm having a little bit of trouble truly understanding how this concept would work. First I'm going to use the devise gem for user authentication and activation, but I need to know how my migrations should look. I have a unique key (user will be given) that will be used to activate an account.

So here's what my code looks like VERY early on, mind you:

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :safe
  has_many :contacts
end
```

Safe Model

```
class Safe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

CreateSafes Migration file

```
class CreateSafes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :saves do |t|
      t.string :safe_key

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

CreateUsers Migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm really just not sure if I add a user_id value to the safe migration table, or whether I just use the safe_key, since that's going to be a totally unique value. Any help and wisdom would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience you never touch the migration files directly, you use the model generator.  You can tell what your tables look like afterward by looking at your schema file.  And if you make a mistake, you just create a new migration to fix it.

Comment: Okay, considering the overall simplicity of the problem at hand, I'd even consider doing it at the Model level, rather than the DB level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, manually add user_id to the safe table.  In associations, rails stores foreign keys in the table with the `:belongs_to`  Then you could use `safe.user` to get the user, or `user.safe` to get the safe.

Comment: Do I also add safe_id to the user table?

Comment: No, you don't have to because of the way Rails handles it's associations.  Even in SQL, with the model the way it is if you had either a safe or a user you could find the other with the appropriate query.